# Code doing arithmetic in loop even though it should be out of the loop

Tags: python

Once I enter q,  I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ossama\Desktop\Pytho\class_code\averages.py", line 9, in <module>      
    given4math=float(given)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'q'
```

This is the code:

```py
count=0
summ=0.0
given4math=0.0
given="a"
while given != 'q':
    given=str(input("Enter a number to be added to the average then hit enter to add the next one, or enter q to quit and have the average calculated: "))
    count+1
    summ=given4math+summ
    given4math=float(given)
else:
    print(summ/count)
```

Comment: You should check the `!= 'q'` condition after you `input(...)` the value

Comment: Right.  And by the way, it is silly to do `str(input(...))`.  The `input` function returns a string.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of the loop in reverse.  You don't want to add `given4math` into `summ` until after you have created `given4math`.

Comment: @TimRoberts This is only true as of python3, which unfortunately is not the only python out there in the wild.. Some people (particularly many of the slower-to-update linux distros, and programs that have embedded python for scripting) still ship 2.7 by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for "q" before you use the value.  You need to convert `given` to float BEFORE you add it in to the sum.  The statement `count+1` does nothing; it computes count + 1 and throws it away.  This should work.

```
count=0
summ=0.0
while True:
    given=input("Enter a number to be added to the average then hit enter to add the next one, or enter q to quit and have the average calculated: ")
    if given == 'q':
        break
    count += 1
    given4math=float(given)
    summ=given4math+summ
print(summ/count)
```

Answer (score 0):

While @Tim Robert's answer is correct, it will break your code if the user gives an input other than a number, or the letter 'q'. So if the user enters 'a' by mistake, it will throw an error. To address that, use try-except blocks to handle these errors.

```
count=0
summ=0.0
while True:
    given=input("Enter a number to be added to the average then hit enter to add the next one, or enter q to quit and have the average calculated: ")
    if given == 'q':
        break
    count += 1
    try:
        given4math=float(given)
    except:
        print("Invalid Input, please try again!")
        continue
    summ=given4math+summ
print(summ/count)
```

Comment: Thanks for this as well, I don't think my class got that far yet but this will be useful later